# Using session during a long task with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

In a program using sqlalchemy, I'm writting a feature which runs a long task with the following steps:

1. get some objects from database
2. do calls to external APIs with data related to objects fetched from db at 1.
3. process results from 2. to create objects in purpose to be inserted after in database (it might calls data from db)
4. insert objects in database

I would like to avoid having a living database transaction during 2. and 3. steps, but I want to keep objects got from 1., and to prepare objects to insert in database during 3.

Currently, there is a single session and I call `commit` at end of 1. (to finish a potential transaction) but it doesn't seem to be enough.

What is the correct pattern?